# Fitting columns in QTableView

Tags: c++, qt, grid, qtableview

In my TableModel I've two columns. This model is connected to the TableView. How can I set them up so those two columns fill the tableView so there is no free space?
EDIT:
[image]

Comment: [Auto-resize columns to fit parent](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34190094)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
tableView->horizontalHeader()->setStretchLastSection(true);
tableView->resizeColumnsToContents(); // not necessarily but can make look better
```

Comment: don't see in my interface for tableView setStretchLastSection

Comment: Well, how do you declare your table view?

Comment: I've dragged it from qt's Item Views section/Model based on my dialog.

Comment: tableView->horizontalHeader()->setStretchLastSection(true); Thanks

Comment: my bad, missed horizontal header. Updated the answer now.