# Columns auto-resize to the size of QTableView

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

I have just managed to make a `QTableView` work with my model. It has fixed 3 columns. When I open a window, it looks ok, but when I resize the window, the `QTableView` itself gets resized, but columns' width remains the same.

I want columns to resize to fit the edges of `QTableView` every time the window gets resized.

Is there any built-in way to make it work?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

There is a header flag to ensure that the QTableView's last column fills up its parent if resized. You can set it like so:

```
table_view->horizontalHeader()->setStretchLastSection(true);
```

However, that does not resize the other columns proportionately. If you want to do that as well, you could handle it inside the resizeEvent of your parent thusly:

```
void QParent::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event) {
    table_view->setColumnWidth(0, this->width()/3);
    table_view->setColumnWidth(1, this->width()/3);
    table_view->setColumnWidth(2, this->width()/3);

    QMainWindow::resizeEvent(event);
}
```

QParent class is subclass of QMainWindow.

Answer (score 103):

This code equally stretches each column so that they fit the table's width.

```
table->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Stretch);
```

Docs:

- [QHeaderView::setSectionResizeMode](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#setSectionResizeMode)
- See resize modes [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#ResizeMode-enum).

Answer (score 8):

Widgets [QTableView](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtableview.html), [QTreeView](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtreeview.html) and their derived classes (such as [QTableWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtablewidget.html)) have this two usefull methods:

```
QHeaderView* horizontalHeader() const;
QHeaderView* verticalHeader() const;
```

If you open documentation for a class [QHeaderView](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qheaderview.html), you will find methods that set up appearance and behavior of row or column header for item views. You can resolve your problem by one of these methods:

1. [void QHeaderView::stretchLastSection( bool stretch )](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qheaderview.html#stretchLastSection-prop)
   As [Davy Jones](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18296115/1536843) mentioned.

   *Example:*

   ```
   QTableView *table = new QTableView();  
   table->horizontalHeader()->setStretchLastSection(true);
   ```
2. [void QHeaderView::setResizeMode( ResizeMode mode )](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qheaderview.html#setResizeMode)
   As *mode* you can set QHeaderView::Stretch or QHeaderView::ResizeToContents.
   Unfortunately this method have a drawback - after it's apply you will not be able to change size of columns (or rows) manually (in GUI) or programmatically.

   *Example:*

   ```
   QTableView *table = new QTableView();  
   table->horizontalHeader()->setResizeMode(QHeaderView::Stretch);
   ```

Answer (score 6):

In PyQt5 you can achieve this in your table_widget by doing:

```
header = table_widget.horizontalHeader()
header.setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
```

Comment: If you are using PyQt6, it becomes: `header.setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeMode.ResizeToContents)`