# Qt QTableView resize to fit content

Tags: python, c++, qt, pyside, qtableview

[image: MainWindow]

Hi, I have created MainWindow as shown above. I want to expand the first widget (plots) as much as possible so that the other two widgets fit content (or actually, I want to remove white empty space below tables).
I don't know how to do that.

Currently, both table vertical header size policy is set to FitToContent.

Also, it needs to be dynamic so if I add a new row to the table, a new row should be visible (table will be larger).

I hope I'm clear enough, and also hope there is no need for runnable code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Columns auto-resize to size of QTableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18293403/columns-auto-resize-to-size-of-qtableview)

Comment: @Ivanovic nope that is not it.I need to reduce height, not strech existing rows.
Couldn't open link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I figure it out.

Reimplementing the resizeEvent will do the trick.

```
    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super(Table, self).resizeEvent(event)
        height = self.horizontalHeader().height()
        for row in range(self.model().rowCount()):
            height += self.rowHeight(row)

        if self.horizontalScrollBar().isVisible():
            height += self.horizontalScrollBar().height()
        self.setMaximumHeight(height + 2)
```

I'm changing the height of QTableView. I'm including height of horizontal header + height of all rows + height of horizontalScrollBar if it is visible.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: It should be noted that since this only takes effect after a resize event, it may have unwanted results. Most importantly, if the model row count changes in the meantime, **any** resize event would change the maximum height abruptly and inconsistently with what was previously shown before the resize, also possibly causing some level of recursion under certain conditions if the height change toggles the visibility of the vertical scroll bar. The added 2 is also completely arbitrary, while it should at least be based on the [`frameWidth()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qframe.html#frameWidth-prop).