# PyQT5 sizing issue with QTableView and QGridLayout

Tags: python, user-interface, layout, pyqt5, qtableview

I built a GUI program that has outputs on single line tables, and I recently updated it using QGridLayout to make it dynamically adjust to different system scalings.

The issue I'm having is the pandas table I load into the QTableView widget seems to be expanding the row to take up a ridiculously large amount of space in the window:

[image: Demonstration of Scaling issue]

I have tried setting the minimum row height using setRowHeight( ... ) to a smaller value and setting setRowStretch to 0, but it doesn't do anything. Resizing the table object also has no effect.

Here is the code:

```
# Table Results
self.Table = QTableView()
__dfwa = pd.DataFrame()
__dfwa['# of Neighbours']                      = np.array([None])
__dfwa['Weighted Average Percent Removal [%]'] = np.array([None])
__modelwa                                      = pandasModel(__dfwa)
self.Table.setModel(__modelwa)
self.Table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(0, self.Table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(1, QHeaderView.Stretch)
self.vbox.addWidget(self.Table, 49,15,1,22)
```

Where self.vbox is called using:

```
self.vbox = QGridLayout()
```

I also know it isn't another object on this row causing issues because if the table is deleted, then the whole GUI rescales to its proper proportions.

I've tried:

```
self.Table.resize(375, 20)
```

and

```
self.vbox.setRowMinimumHeight(49,20)
self.vbox.setRowStretch(49,0)
```

I've changed up the values in the functions and it has no effect. If anyone has run into this issue before and found a solution it would be very helpful as I've been stuck on this for a while now. Thanks in advance!

**CLARIFICATION**

Since my original question was unclear, here is what I mean. This is *HOW I WANT IT TO LOOK*:

[image: How I would like the GUI to look]

This is *HOW IT ACTUALLY LOOKS*:

[image: How the actual GUI Looks]

**Possible Solution**

I think I've found an imperfect workaround for now, I've added this code:

```
for _i in range(__nRowsMain):
    if _i == 49:
        self.vbox.setRowStretch(_i, 1)
    self.vbox.setRowMinimumHeight(_i, __perH)
    self.vbox.setRowStretch(_i, 0)
```

Where `__nRowsMain` is the total number of rows in my grid, and `__perH` is an integer value I set the rest of the row heights. It's not perfect but it's better than nothing.

Comment: I suppose you're referring to the *width* of the view, then calling`setRowMinimumHeight()` and `setRowStretch()` is obviously pointless: as the name should suggest, they refer to the *row height*, while you should control the *column width* (or stretch). Then, are you sure about those row/column arguments in `addWidget()`? It seems a bit odd that the layout has 50 rows and 37 columns, if you're trying to use those values to achieve "larger" rows and columns, then it's wrong, since those indices only refer to logical position and have absolutely no relation to the actual size of each grid item.

Comment: @musicamante no I am indeed referring to the height, as you can see my single row table is vertically stretching the row height to a massive degree, giving me roughly 4x the space the table actually needs to be fully displayed.

The application is quite large, so yes I am sure they are in the correct row/column position. I am not using those values to artificially inflate the size of the section, but because I have lots of other widgets within the application.

Comment: @Tom Your question is quite unclear. I suggest you add another screenshot which shows the *behaviour you actually expect* (and/or annotate the existing screenshot to clarify the specific space you are referring to).

Comment: @ekhumoro I've added some clarification, hopefully that helps. I think I found a potential solution, it isn't perfect and still leaves a bit of extra height space in the Table widget but the scaling is a little less ridiculous

Comment: Does this answer your question: [QTableView resize to fit content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62471810/984421)?

Comment: @Tom Note that the solution proposed as duplicated may not work as expected, especially since it only changes the maximum height upon `resizeEvent()`, meaning that: 1. it's not dynamic (if you want to adapt the height whenever the model changes, it won't work until the window is resized or any sibling widget causes the layout to reactivate itself); 2. when a sibling widget or the window cause a resize event, and the model has changed before that, you'll see table height "jumping". You should clarify if the required height should be dynamic, and/or it should consider a maximum count.