# User interactions with column width in QTreeWidget

Tags: qt, qtreewidget

I am using QTreeWidget to display a table with data, and want to see if there is any way to allow the user to change the width of the columns when the data are displayed.

```
QTreeWidget qtw = new QTreeWidget(qgb[0]);
qtw->setColumnCount(10);
QStringList labels = {"Label 1", "Label 2", "Label 3", "Label 4", "Label 5", "Label 6", "Label 7", "Label 8", "Label 9", "Label 10"};
qtw->setHeaderLabels(labels);

// After that I go on and populate the columns
```

However, when the code is run, the user has no control over the column width (i.e., cannot change it).

Is there any way to let the user do it?

Comment: Please see [`QTreeView::header`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html#header) and [`QHeaderView::setSectionResizeMode`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#setSectionResizeMode).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Columns auto-resize to the size of QTableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18293403/columns-auto-resize-to-the-size-of-qtableview)